# google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream does not write anything if the file handle is closed at the end

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, gzipoutputstream

The following code writes to file as expected

```
  int ofd = open(filename.c_str(),  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
  google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream outp(ofd);
  google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream fout(&outp);

  MyMessage msg;
  ConstructMessage(&msg);
  CHECK(google::protobuf::util::SerializeDelimitedToZeroCopyStream(msg, &fout));
  fout.Close();
  // close(ofd);
```

However if I uncomment the last line `// close(ofd);`, I get empty file. Why is that?

Also if I skip using the Gzip wrapper, the last line causes no problem. Does this look like a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close things in the opposite order of opening:

```
int ofd = open(filename.c_str(),  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream outp(ofd);
google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream fout(&outp);

...

fout.Close();
outp.Close();
close(ofd);
```

With the missing `outp.Close();`, some data may remain buffered in it. The destructor will eventually flush it out, but at that point the `ofd` is already closed so there is nothing to write to.